# rust set cursor position for user input

Tags: rust, terminal

I'm a newbie rust programmer and I'm writing a program that prints a table, and using a loop, gets the numeric values from the user and each time the user enters the value, the table gets updated and printed again until all the values are received.

```
            class1      class2      class3      class4      class5
Sensor      0           0           0           0           0
visual      0           0           0           0           0
```

I want to put the cursor at the desired cell (and blink if possible) which the user is going to enter the value for. Which means at first iteration the cursor should be at the cell `sensor-class1`, 2nd iteration at the `sensor-class2` and so on.

I searched for a while and seems that [termion](https://crates.io/crates/termion/1.5.6) is the solution, but `print!("{}", termion::cursor::Goto((10 * i).try_into().unwrap(), j));`
shifts the printed table in each iteration and not the user input cursor:

```
extern crate termion;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut sensor_data = [0; 5];
    let mut visual_data = [0; 5];

    for j in 1..3 {
        for i in 1..6 {
            print!("{}", termion::clear::All);
            print!("{}", termion::cursor::Goto(1, 1));

            println!(
                "{0: <10}  {1: <10}  {2: <10}  {3: <10}  {4: <10}  {5: <10}",
                "", "class1", "class2", "class3", "class4", "class5"
            );
            println!(
                "{0: <10}  {1: <10}  {2: <10}  {3: <10}  {4: <10}  {5: <10}",
                "Sensor",
                sensor_data[0],
                sensor_data[1],
                sensor_data[2],
                sensor_data[3],
                sensor_data[4]
            );
            println!(
                "{0: <10}  {1: <10}  {2: <10}  {3: <10}  {4: <10}  {5: <10}",
                "visual",
                visual_data[0],
                visual_data[1],
                visual_data[2],
                visual_data[3],
                visual_data[4]
            );

            //update the cursor position for user input

            let mut input = String::new();
            io::stdin()
                .read_line(&mut input)
                .expect("Failed to read line");
            if j == 1 {sensor_data[i - 1] = input.trim().parse().expect("Please type a number!");}
            else {visual_data[i - 1] = input.trim().parse().expect("Please type a number!");}
        }
    }
// print the complete table and go on
}
```

Comment: `extern crate` is really old rust, use `use` instead. Although unrelated to your question, of course.

Comment: The `termion` crate is rather low-level. Without having looked at the details of this question, I think you may have an easier time with a higher-level crate. As an example, the [`tui` crate provides a `Table` widget](https://docs.rs/tui/latest/tui/widgets/struct.Table.html) that looks like a good fit. The `tui` crate can use `termion` as its backend. The default is the more portable `crossterm`, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think primarily, you are missing a `stdout().flush()`.

`print!()`, contrary to `println!()`, does **not** write a newline character. On most systems a newline character causes a flush, but as there is no newline character, the `Goto` gets stuck in the write buffer.

An easy fix would be to `flush()` manually, as shown in the code sample below.

The more proper way, though, would be to access the terminal in *raw* mode to disable the buffer in the first place.

```rust
use std::io::{self, Write};

fn main() {
    let mut sensor_data = [0; 5];
    let mut visual_data = [0; 5];

    for j in 1..3 {
        for i in 1..6 {
            print!("{}", termion::clear::All);
            print!("{}", termion::cursor::Goto(1, 1));

            println!(
                "{0: <10}  {1: <10}  {2: <10}  {3: <10}  {4: <10}  {5: <10}",
                "", "class1", "class2", "class3", "class4", "class5"
            );
            println!(
                "{0: <10}  {1: <10}  {2: <10}  {3: <10}  {4: <10}  {5: <10}",
                "Sensor",
                sensor_data[0],
                sensor_data[1],
                sensor_data[2],
                sensor_data[3],
                sensor_data[4]
            );
            println!(
                "{0: <10}  {1: <10}  {2: <10}  {3: <10}  {4: <10}  {5: <10}",
                "visual",
                visual_data[0],
                visual_data[1],
                visual_data[2],
                visual_data[3],
                visual_data[4]
            );

            //update the cursor position for user input
            print!("{}", termion::cursor::Goto(12 * i + 1, j + 1));
            io::stdout().flush().unwrap();

            let mut input = String::new();
            io::stdin()
                .read_line(&mut input)
                .expect("Failed to read line");
            if j == 1 {
                sensor_data[i as usize - 1] = input.trim().parse().expect("Please type a number!");
            } else {
                visual_data[i as usize - 1] = input.trim().parse().expect("Please type a number!");
            }
        }
    }
    // print the complete table and go on
}
```

---

Other minor fixes I added:

- Remove `extern crate` as it is no longer required or advised
- Change type of `i` to `u16` and convert to `usize` instead of the other way round, to avoid the `unwrap()`

Comment: "`print!()`, contrary to `println!()`, does not automatically flush stdout." Neither of the two macros automatically flushes stdout. It's just that stdout is often line-buffered, so it gets implicitly flushed as soon as you send a newline character, regardless of whether you do that with `print!()` or `println!()`. For this application, the OP probably wants to put the terminal in "raw mode", though, which is a vaguely defined set of terminal settings that usually include unbuffered mode, i.e. everything that's written gets immediately flushed.

Comment: Makes sense.  I adjusted my answer slightly.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll settle with the "easy fix" for now. I'm not familiar with the syntax and it's really confusing. 
Although the cursor coordination is not clear to me. Why the columns are shifted 12 characters despite the `<10` in the `println!`? and why did you use `12*i+1` instead of `12*i`?

Comment: Because you have two spaces between the `{}` statements in your strings. The `+1` is because the top-left cursor is `(1,1)` and not `(0,0)`. For more information, read the documentation of [Goto](https://docs.rs/termion/1.5.1/termion/cursor/struct.Goto.html): `Goto some position ((1,1)-based).`.